# Legacy Firefox throws error: libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, firefox, libdbus

I'm working on the legacy code which requires the outdated FF to run functional tests. After downloading [FF 41](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/41.0/linux-x86_64/en-GB/) and unpacking it to `/opt` I can launch it successfully from console via
`$ /opt/firefox/firefox`

the problem is that I can not run it from Intellij IDEA 2022.2.3. I added proper VM options to test run config:

```
-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=/opt/firefox/firefox
-Dgeb.driver=firefox
```

however it throws an exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:221)
```

I already tried:

- `sudo apt install --reinstall libdbus-glib-1-2 #reinstalling`
- `sudo apt install libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 #installing 386 version`
- `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v #handling shared libs according to https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/`

unfortunately nothing works.
How to handle it? Similar config seems to work on similar desktop with the old Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Comment: I was receiving same error creating a container for testing purposes. I fixed installing these dependencies: libgtk-3-0 libdbus-glib-1-2 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with package manager (snap or flatpak - I don't remember anymore). Apparently we should avoid using it to install any software (in this case Intellij), cause it's a root cause of such issues!